# "From" missing in header using AWS SES Email API using AWS-SDK in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use Amazon SES for sending mail(with or without attachments) using AWS-SDK and `sendRawEmail()`.
But it always bounces back with the error "From" is missing in header.

The code is as followed:

```
$header .= "From: abc@abc.com \r\n ";
$header .= "To: def@def.com \r\n ";
$header .= "Reply-To: abc@abc.com \r\n ";
$header .= "Subject: Testing Attachments \r\n ";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n ";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n ";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit \r\n \r\n ";
$header .= "This is normal content \r\n ";




$result = $client->sendRawEmail(
                    array('RawMessage' => array('Data' => base64_encode($header)), 'Source' => 'abc@abc.com', 'Destinations' => array('def@def.com'), 'SourceArn' => 'arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:1234:identity/abc@abc.com', 'FromArn' => 'arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:1234:identity/abc@abc.com')
                );
```

If I don't give "Source", "Destinations" in `sendRawEmail()` then it gives error "From" header is missing and if those parameters are given that the mail bounces with the same error.

Thanks in advance for helping me out finding the solution for the same.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but there should be **no** space character before each `\r\n`.  There definitely should be none at the end of the message.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue when using another language SDK.

```
base64_encode($header)
```

Don't encode it. Remove `base64_encode`

Comment: InvalidParameterValue (client): Nested group - Sender InvalidParameterValue Nested group 
Then this error occurs.

Comment: Thanks, removing `base64_encode()` worked for me when I upgraded from v2 to v3 of the aws php sdk.